# how to reset theme of vscode

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have made some changes and landed into below thing where green colour tab came from no where.

I deleted the vscode and reinstalled it via snap but still the problem exists.

I'm new to ubuntu and whatever I do ubuntu is giving problems everywhere and I found no answer for resetting vscode colours so anyone please help me.

[image]

Comment: after using the extension `Window Colors stuart.unique-window-colors`  I uninstalled it. and my editor get into trouble

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this is easy but no one ever documented it well.

in vscode if a project is opened then .vscode folder will get created. in that .vscode folder settings.json was there. if it is cleared then the above problem will go.

most of the time i changed settings.json under user tab. but if i have changed settings.json under workspace tab the issue would have fixed earlier.

Comment: you can also edit your settings.json file